# Stop current running cron job(isp manager)

Tags: php, cron

I've executed a cron job, that has executed my php function:

```
   public function run($arguments)
    {
        restart:
        DB::query('insert into test(`label`) values ("run")');
        sleep(1);
        goto restart;
    }
```

so it is looping and each second adding a record to the DB, i've deleted the task from the cron job list, but the process still works, how do i stop it without restarting the server, I can use SSH also

Comment: Look for it with `ps -ef | grep cron` and then make a `kill <pid>`, where PID is the ID of the process you want to stop.

Comment: this kills the cron manager, but not the running process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`killall -9 php`;
```

in PHP or shell kills all the php-processes. or do `kill -9 PID` where PID is the process id of the php-job.

Comment: But what if there are other processes with `php`? I recommend being careful with `killall` commands.

Comment: I warned him. Else you can do `ps -ef | grep 'filename-here'` and do kill -9